# C++ Variable with same value across all instances of class using type and functions dependent on class

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a 2D array of function pointers that will have the same value across all instances (millions!) of the class.

```
class Foo{
    public:

    ...

    ...
    static int bar1(const Foo& foo_1, const Foo& foo_2);
    static int bar2(const Foo& foo_1, const Foo& foo_2);
    static int bar3(const Foo& foo_1, const Foo& foo_2);
    static int bar4(const Foo& foo_1, const Foo& foo_2);

    static int bar4(const Foo& foo_1, const Foo& foo_2);

    friend bool foobar_func(const Foo& foo_1, const Foo& foo_2) {
    ...
```

My 2D array is something like:

```
int (*fcn_pointers[2][2])( const Foo&, const Foo&) = { 
                                                    {&Foo::bar1, &Foo::bar2},
                                                    {&Foo::bar3, &Foo::bar4}
                                                  }
```

For the life of me, I can not get this 2D array to be initialized once and then used inside of `foobar_func`. I am running into issues because the types depend on the class that it is a member of.

Is this even possible? Performance is **very** important here -- the whole point that I am doing this is to increase performance (which it will, if it works). So adding a conditional to check whether or not it is initialized is not something I can afford.

I am not familiar with C++ -- my entire experience with C++ is based off of a weekend of looking over this source code, so I am probably missing something obvious. My use for C++ does not need to go deeper than problems like this, so learning C++ is not a priority (though maybe a link to some 'gotchas' about it would help_. I am a PhD student familiar with Java, C and Python, so I do understand object oriented programming, just not how to solve this with C++.

I tried to do something like this but it says the linker cannot find `Foo::bar1` etc.

```
class Foo{
    public:

    static int bar1(const Foo& foo_1, const Foo& foo_2);
    static int bar2(const Foo& foo_1, const Foo& foo_2);

    friend bool foobar_func(const Foo& foo_1, const Foo& foo_2) {
       return false;
    }

};

int (*fcn_pointers[2][2])( const Foo&, const Foo&) = { 
                             {&Foo::bar1, &Foo::bar2},
                             {&Foo::bar1, &Foo::bar2}
                                              };


admin@test:~/test$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
/tmp/ccN4yJ56.o:(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `Foo::bar1(Foo const&, Foo const&)'
/tmp/ccN4yJ56.o:(.data+0x8): undefined reference to `Foo::bar2(Foo const&, Foo const&)'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of the difficulty. Just make `fcn_pointers` a global variable.

Comment: If `fcn_pointers` is fixed, then you should make it const, that may improve performance. You may also find it easier to make the function pointer a typedef and then use it. It just simplifies the syntax.

Comment: I have tried that but I come into issues with it saying that the type `Foo` has not been created yet. Ex:

error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'parameter' with no type [-fpermissive]

error: 'Foo' has not been declared

Comment: Put the typedef in the class, or forward-declare `Foo` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve the problem:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static int bar1(const Foo& foo_1, const Foo& foo_2);
    static int bar2(const Foo& foo_1, const Foo& foo_2);
    static int bar3(const Foo& foo_1, const Foo& foo_2);
    static int bar4(const Foo& foo_1, const Foo& foo_2);

    typedef int(*fcn_pointers_type)(const Foo&, const Foo&);

    static const fcn_pointers_type funcs[2][2];
};

// put in a source file
const Foo::fcn_pointers_type funcs[2][2] = { { &Foo::bar1, &Foo::bar2 }, { &Foo::bar3, &Foo::bar4 } };
```

Comment: Wouldn't that require every single instance to have the same function pointers? And I would still have to worry about having to only get it initialized *once*.

Comment: @user1661781 It will only be initialized once, and every instance will share the same function pointers. If that's not what you want, please clarify how the function pointers associated with each instance are determined.

Comment: I tried this (having your exact code in test.h, and making a test.cpp), and am getting the following error:

    #include "test.h"


    const Foo::fcn_pointers_type funcs[2][2] = { { &Foo::bar1, &Foo::bar2 }, { &Foo::bar3, &Foo::bar4 } };
    int main() {}



    admin@test:~/test$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
    /tmp/cciFWSfe.o:(.rodata+0x0): undefined reference to     `Foo::bar1(Foo const&, Foo const&)'


    /tmp/cciFWSfe.o:(.rodata+0x8): undefined reference to     `Foo::bar2(Foo const&, Foo const&)'

Comment: @user1661781 You do implement these functions at some point, right?

Comment: Well, that would probably help. I got distracted doing the small example and tried to do it on that. Thanks, this worked.